# Replacing Comcast modem/router with my own for internet and phone

Tags: router, internet, modem

I use Comcast for my wireless internet and land-line phone at home. I'm interested in buying my own router instead of using the one Comcast is "letting" me use for "only" $10/month.

I've looked around and it seems this is a pretty common decision, but my question is: will my phone service still work with a non-Comcast router? And if so could you point me in the right direction for what I should be looking for to get it to work?

I should note that the router is a modem/router all in one device.

Comment: It is harder to find modem/routers with phone, but they can be bought.  The better question is why not ditch the landline? We haven't missed ours at all. Taking phone out of the picture opens up your hardware choices dramatically.

Comment: @Tyson tell me about it. :/ this is actually for my parents who insist on keeping their land line. So it's not really an option.

Comment: FWIW I prefer standalone modem and standalone router, but you can't get what your parents need that way... I did tell you what you need to know in an answer... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really isn't a hardware recommendation site but search Amazon for "docsis 3.0 modem phone" and you'll find what you need (note: Amazon search sucks it includes modems without phone too), some even say Comcast certified. However others may be as well, check [this Comcast list](http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/).

Make sure whatever you buy is on that list, is docsis 3.0, and IPv6 compatible, anything else and you're buying out of date technology.  I'd want an "ac" class wifi (2.4 and 5.0ghz)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about the hardware that Comcast rents out. You should be able to buy the same device, or a better version of the device and do a straight replacement. You will have to reconfigure the new device, so make sure you copy down the settings from the old one.

Comment: WIth no issues to my phone service?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a problem there, phones and internet are different. And some tips on a router, don't buy cheap stuff. I would recommend something AC, or N, but remember, you cant expect 100meg downloads from your router, if A: your device doesn't support ac, and B: if your not paying for 100meg internet. No WiFi will be faster than a wired connection.